# need quit the macro when value reaches at the end of row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that performs certain task when it encounters an non empty cell in a row. Below code i am using to check for each non-empty cell but the problem is arises after the last non empty cell is encountered. Last value it takes A1048576 and then my excel hangs.

Row

Reg_SCN_001

Reg_SCN_002

Reg_SCN_003

```
If VBA.IsEmpty(startCell.Value) Then
      'MsgBox "No data in this column"
Else
       Set firstNonEmptyCell = startCell.End(xlDown)
      'MsgBox "First non empty cell is " & firstNonEmptyCell.Address
       county = firstNonEmptyCell.Offset(0, 0).Address(False, False)
       county = Right(county, Len(county) - 1)
       countsteps1 = county - 1
End If
```

The above code give the cell address of each non empty cell which i use in my program. example Reg001 @ $A$2, Reg001 @ $A$16, Reg002 @ $A$33 so on.
So what happens after it reaches the last non empty cell say Reg015 @ $A$233.
The above code runs more time and give me the end of row cell value i.e. $A$1048576 and i want to stop at Reg015 @ $A$233 which is the last non-empty cell.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You've not provided enough code to troubleshoot this. It's likely a problem with something else in the sub/function such as an incorrectly coded loop.

Comment: as @Zerk stated, your question is unclear; but, generally speaking, if you want to "quit macro" as you said, you can use `Exit Sub`.

Comment: Let me explain a bit more.

Comment: would something like "IF variable.row = lastrow and variable.column = lastcolumn then exit sub"  work?

Answer (score 0):

If your "If ... End If" is in a "For ... Next" loop, then you can exit with "Exit For".

Example :

```
If VBA.IsEmpty(startCell.Value) Then
      'MsgBox "No data in this column"
      Exit For
Else
....
```

If your "If ... End If" is in a "Do While ... " loop, then you can exit with "Exit Do".

But if you want to exit the entire Sub, use "Exit Sub".